# Excel - using Userform checkboxes to determine what sheets to be called

Tags: string, vba, checkbox

I would like to select multiple worksheet depending on the userform checkboxes status and I am receiving error at the selection. I have a total of 16 checkboxes in my userform, so I need a method to determine the sheets to be selected.

> Short Example:

```
 `Sub chkboxes()'

DIM SheetNames as string  

If CB1.value = true then  
   SheetNames = "SummaryReport"  
End IF

If CB2.value = true and sheetNames <> "" then  
    SheetNames = Sheetnames & "," & "WeekdaysReport"  
elseif CB2.value = true and sheetnames = "" then  
    SheetNames = "WeekdaysReport"  
End If

If CB3.value = true and sheetnames <> "" then  
    SheetNames = SheetNames & "," & "WeekendsReport"  
elseif CB3.value = true and SheetNames <> "" then  
    SheetNames = "WeekendsReport"  
End If

If SheetNames = ""  
    Exit Sub  
End If

Sheets(Array(SheetNames)).select   **'This is where the script stops and prompt error.**  
Call ExportToPDF  

SheetNames = ""

End Sub
```

The above is pretty amateur, I am still very unfamiliar with vba and programming. Hopefully i could get some guidance. Thanks.

I have tried searching for solution online, but failed to find similar post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is unnecessary call of "Array" function in your code and few other "shortcuts".

Please replace following lines:

```
Sheets(Array(SheetNames)).select
Call ExportToPDF
```

with this snippet:

```
Dim aSheetNames() As String
Dim i as long

aSheetNames = Split(SheetNames,",")

For i = LBound(aSheetNames) To UBound(aSheetNames)
    Sheets(aSheetNames(i)).select 
    ExportToPDF
Next
```

And, I hope, now procedure should works if my assumptions was right.

Ups, I have found another issue...
If I'm correctly guessing your intensions, the resposible code for each CheckBox should looks like this:

```
If CB2.Value Then  
    If SheetNames <> "" Then SheetNames = Sheetnames & "," 
    SheetNames = Sheetnames & "WeekdaysReport"  
End If
```

Comment: Thanks again, this works. But is it possible to select multiple worksheets at once so I can have them all exported to one single pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way, I think. Rather than checkboxes, use a listbox which can also multi-select. In the code behind your user form do something like this:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
    .AddItem "SummaryReport"
    .AddItem "WeekdaysReport"
    .AddItem "WeekendReport"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With ListBox1
    Dim i As Integer
    Do Until i = .ListCount
        If .Selected(i) Then
        Sheets(.ListIndex + 1).Select
        'MsgBox Sheets(i + 1).Name
        'do something with selected sheet
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually my script contains 16 checkbox, each refers to a range in certain sheet. My objective is to determine which range is in which sheet, I have managed to done that, and have all the sheets name saved in a string. But when I try to select the worksheets using the string, i faced the error.